# Как сделать скрипт расчета угла наклона используя акселерометр и гироскоп для датчика GY-521?

Tags: arduino

Как сделать скрипт который будет рассчитывать угол наклона используя акселерометр и гироскоп, чтобы не было скачков показников при небольшём косании к нему?

Нужно прогонять данный через какие-то фильтры, для сглаживания показаний с датчика?

В интернете нашёл несколько скриптов, но они не годятся для дальнейшей работы.
Вот 1 скрипт который нашёл.

```
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"

#define TO_DEG 57.29577951308232087679815481410517033f
#define T_OUT 20 // каждый 20 миллисекунд будем проводить вычисления 
#define P_OUT 50 // каждый 50 миллисекунд будем выводить данные
#define FK 0.1 // коэффициент комплементарного фильтра

MPU6050 accelgyro;

float angle_ax, angle_gx, angle_cpl;
int dt = 0;
long int t_next, p_next;

// функция, которая не даёт значению выйти за пределы 
float clamp(float v, float minv, float maxv){
    if( v>maxv )
        return maxv;
    else if( v<minv )
        return minv;
    return v;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // инициализация MPU6050
    accelgyro.initialize();
    Serial.println(accelgyro.testConnection() ? "MPU6050 connection successful" : "MPU6050 connection failed");
}

void loop() {
    long int t = millis();
    // каждые T_TO миллисекунд выполняем рассчет угла наклона
    if( t_next < t ){
        int16_t ax_raw, ay_raw, az_raw, gx_raw, gy_raw, gz_raw;
        float ay,gx;

        t_next = t + T_OUT;
        // получаем сырые данные от датчиков в MPU6050
        accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax_raw, &ay_raw, &az_raw, &gx_raw, &gy_raw, &gz_raw);

        // преобразуем сырые данные гироскопа в град/сек
        gx = gx_raw / 16.4;
        // преобразуем сырые данные акселерометра в G
        ay = ay_raw / 4096.0;
        ay = clamp(ay, -1.0, 1.0);

        // вычисляем угол наклона по акселерометру
        angle_ax = 90 - TO_DEG*acos(ay);
        // вычисляем угол наклона по гироскопу
        angle_gx = angle_gx + gx * T_OUT/1000.0;
        // корректируем значение угла с помощью акселерометра
        angle_gx = angle_gx*(1-FK) + angle_ax*FK;
    }

    t = millis();
    // каждые P_OUT миллисекунд выводим результат в COM порт
    if( p_next < t ){
        p_next = t + P_OUT;
        Serial.println(angle_gx);
    }
}
```

А вот второй

```
// MPU6050 & Servo

// byDenisGeek


#include <SPI.h>

#include <Wire.h>

#define MPU 0x68  // I2C address of the MPU-6050


double AcX,AcY,AcZ;

int Pitch, Roll;


void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  init_MPU(); // Inizializzazione MPU6050

}

 

void loop()

{

  FunctionsMPU(); // Acquisisco assi AcX, AcY, AcZ.

    

  Roll = FunctionsPitchRoll(AcX, AcY, AcZ);   //Calcolo angolo Roll

  Pitch = FunctionsPitchRoll(AcY, AcX, AcZ);  //Calcolo angolo Pitch


  int ServoRoll = map(Roll, -90, 90, 0, 179);

  int ServoPitch = map(Pitch, -90, 90, 179, 0);



  Serial.print("Pitch: "); Serial.print(Pitch);

  Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print("Roll: "); Serial.print(Roll);

  Serial.print("\n");


}


void init_MPU(){

  Wire.begin();

  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);

  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register

  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)

  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  delay(1000);

}


//Funzione per il calcolo degli angoli Pitch e Roll

double FunctionsPitchRoll(double A, double B, double C){

  double DatoA, DatoB, Value;

  DatoA = A;

  DatoB = (B*B) + (C*C);

  DatoB = sqrt(DatoB);

  

  Value = atan2(DatoA, DatoB);

  Value = Value * 180/3.14;

  

  return (int)Value;

}


//Funzione per l'acquisizione degli assi X,Y,Z del MPU6050

void FunctionsMPU(){

  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);

  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)

  Wire.endTransmission(false);

  Wire.requestFrom(MPU,6,true);  // request a total of 14 registers

  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)     

  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)

  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)

}
```

Comment: К сожалению, здесь не стол заказов. Поправил ваш вопрос, чтобы он был вопросом. Если вам нужен именно готовый результат - на фрилансе вам с радостью помогут за денежное вознаграждение.

Comment: 1) Т.к. вам нужно менять угол наклона, то акселерометр нет смысла использовать, только гироскоп. 2) Используйте ПИД-регулятор для сглаживания данных.